# sendfile return -1 errno 29 illegal seek

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am using sendfile to send and receive files between the client and server, sending the file is fine, but when receiving the file, it returns -1, and the errno is 29 illegal seek, I am not sure what is wrong.

```
int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
off_t offset = 0;
int ret = sendfile(fd, sockfd, &offset, filelen);
printf("ret = %d errno=%d\n", ret, errno);
>>> ret = -1 errno = 29
```

Comment: If you use `O_CREAT`, you need a third argument to `open()` specifying the mode (permissions) of the file to be created (traditionally, 0666; I recommend 0644 these more security-conscious days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page for [`sendfile()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) says:

> The `in_fd` argument must correspond to a file which supports mmap(2)-like operations (i.e., it cannot be a socket).

The `in_fd` is the second argument, the one you named `sockfd`.  That suggests your problem is that the input file descriptor is not valid for use with `sendfile()`.

Comment: So sendfile should not be used to receive a file from socket?

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I google it and someone said I could receive a file with sendfile..but the man page said no. I should read the man page more carefully, thank you.